# GetPrivateQueuesByMachine error when being called

Tags: c#, message-queue, msmq

I am trying to simply get a list of all the Private Queues on the Server from my PC.

The error I am getting is "Access to Message Queuing system is denied."

I have given full access to (Everyone, NETWORK SERVICE and Anonymous Logon) the queue on the  as there is only 1 queue....

Please see attached error and  code below:-

```
       try
       {
            MessageQueue[] queueList =                
            MessageQueue.GetPrivateQueuesByMachine("xxx.xxx.x.xxx");//Error 
            occurs here

            foreach (MessageQueue queueItem in queueList)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(queueItem.Path);
            }

             return created;
        }
        catch (MessageQueueException m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Message + m.MessageQueueErrorCode);
        }
        catch (SystemException s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Message + s.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On the computer manager of the target machine ("xxx.xxx.x.xxx" in your example) select "Services and applications" and then "Message Queuing". Right click on "Message Queuing", go to secuirty tab and add your account with full control. Thsi should give you access to the private queues on that machine

Comment: Yep, Maiur is failing to talk to the MSMQ service, not the queue.

Comment: Have already done that and given access to ANONYMOUS LOGON, Everyone and NETWORK SERVICE...not sure which other account to give access to...

Comment: Happy to add other accounts - any ideas please?

Comment: @JohnBreakwell - Hi John I am happy to add other accounts as required...I know it's a permissions issue...any further help appreciated...

Comment: Everyone and Anonymous Logon are all you need to effectively include all accounts. If you've added these permissions to the Service, as recommended, and not just the Queue, as you originally posted, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: What account are you using for the app that tries to get the list of queues?
What domain membership is there for the client and server machines? If different domains, are they in the same forest?

Comment: Could try setting NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2007/01/15/msmq-3-0-too-secure-for-you/)

Comment: Also AllowNonauthenticatedRPC (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/02/12/msmq-4-0-whats-new-in-computer-management/)